# parse deploy error in mac os

Tags: macos, python-2.7, parse-platform

I am following the sample code and instructions given [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios). I created `Parse` account and an `app` in it.

I also installed `Parse` using

`curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash` in MAC OS.

Now when I run `parse deploy` command from terminal, I get the following error stack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 696, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 202, in handle_deploy
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/parse.py", line 110, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/parse.py", line 118, in load_state
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/config_handler.py", line 125, in get_keys_for_app
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/config_handler.py", line 100, in get_info_for_apps
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/config_handler.py", line 112, in get_app_info_for_file
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 3 column 9 (char 32)
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have the project set up:

[image]

Ensure your global.json file is well-configured. For example:

```
{
    "applications": {
        "YOUR_APP_NAME": {
            "applicationId": "YOUR_APP_ID", 
            "masterKey": "YOUR_MASTER_KEY"
        }, 
        "ANOTHER_APP_NAME": {
            "applicationId": "ANOTHER_APP_ID", 
            "masterKey": "ANOTHER_MASTER_KEY"
        }, 
        "_default": {
            "link": "YOUR_APP_NAME"
        }
    }, 
    "global": {
        "parseVersion": "1.2.18"
    }
}
```

So from terminal, go in the folder at the same level of "cloud","config","public","test"
and run the command "parse deploy" that will call the deploy for the default app "YOUR_APP_NAME" ( change it to "ANOTHER_APP_NAME" if you have other app at which send that cloud code, for example a develop app and production app).

Ensure to have the "**main.js**" file in the "**cloud**" folder, and a sample **index.html** file in the "**public**" folder

If you have parse installed properly , you should be able to work with it.

Hope it helps